# OR relationship between places

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using google place api to fetch the nearby locations in my android application. And I successfully implemented it using this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/). Now, here using ' | ' symbol we can get places of more than one types. e.g.  `types  = "amusement_park | bakery"` will return places of both the amusement_park and bakery within given radius. But in some regions these two places might not be available simultaneously. So, I want only result of either of two places. Suppose in region A there is only bakery is available, so I will get only nearby bakeries. But with this ' | 'symbol I am not getting any result. Or I can say this ' | ' is behaving like AND operator. But I want OR kind of relationship between places. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide the URL you are using when you are not getting the results that you expect?

Comment: String types  = "amusement_park | bakery | bar | book_store | cafe | clothing_store | convenience_store | department_store | electronics_store | florist | food | gas_station | grocery_or_supermarket | hair_care | hardware_store | health | home_goods_store | liquor_store | meal_delivery | meal_takeaway | movie_rental | pet_store | restaurant | shoe_store | shopping_mall | store | university " ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove space between two types and test it...

```
String types  = "amusement_park|bakery|bar|book_store|cafe|clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|gas_station|grocery_or_supermarket|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_store|liquor_store|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|movie_rental|pet_store|restaurant|shoe_store|shopping_mall|store|university" ;
```